# Issue with CoreText CTFrameGetLineOrigins in Swift

Tags: swift, core-text

I have the following code working in Objective-C

```
NSArray *lines = (NSArray *)CTFrameGetLines((__bridge CTFrameRef)columnFrame);
CGPoint origins[[lines count]];
CTFrameGetLineOrigins((__bridge CTFrameRef)columnFrame, CFRangeMake(0, 0), origins);
```

But when ported to Swift, the compiler complains with a `Cannot convert the expression´s ´Void´to type ´CMutablePointer<CGPoint>` in the `CTFrameGetLineOrigins` line

```
let nsLinesArray: NSArray = CTFrameGetLines(ctFrame) // Use NSArray to bridge to Array
let ctLinesArray = nsLinesArray as Array
var originsArray: Array<CGPoint> = CGPoint[]()
//var originsArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray.array()
let range: CFRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0)
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(ctFrame, range, originsArray)
```

I had to use NSArray in the `CGFrameGetLines` function, and then convert to a Swift Array, and inspecting the ctLinesArray, shows that the `CTLine` objects are retrieved correctly

I tried using `NSMutableArray` for the originsArray, with the same result.

Any idea of what is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the address-of operator `&` to pass the pointer to the 
start of the `originsArray` to the function:

```
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(ctFrame, range, &originsArray)
```

Reference: [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13)
in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" book:

> **C Mutable Pointers**
>
> When a function is declared as taking a `CMutablePointer<Type>`
>   argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - ...
> - An in-out `Type[]` value,
>     which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array, and
>     lifetime-extended for the duration of the call.

And from [Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Expressions.html) in "The Swift Programming Language" book:

> In addition to the standard library operators listed above, you use `&`
>   immediately before the name of a variable that’s being passed as an
>   in-out argument to a function call expression.

An addition (as @eharo2 already figured out), the `originsArray` must have room for the
necessary number of elements, which can be achieved with

```
var originsArray = CGPoint[](count:ctLinesArray.count, repeatedValue: CGPointZero)
```

Comment: #Martin R. I had done that, even though the Objective-C version does´t use the memory address, the Swift documentation refers to origins as a buffer . With that the compiles doesn´t report any issue, but then I have a run time EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: @eharo2: OK, I have only compiled it. I have added some references from the documentation which should explain why `&` is correct. But I cannot explain why it crashes at runtime. That would require a complete running CoreText app which I do not have.

Comment: #Martin R. Thx for the additional background.  As you point the "&" fixes the compiler error.   I found a way to deal with the run time error as follows: I loaded the originsArray with CGPointZero (one for each line reported by CTFrameGetLines. `for _ in 0..ctLinesArray.count {
            originsArray.append(CGPointZero)
        }`

Comment: @eharo2: You are right, the must already have the necessary number of elements. You probably can simplify the creation to `var originsArray = CGPoint[](count:ctLinesArray.count, repeatedValue: CGPointZero)` .